# Modificar enlace productos Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Intento modificar el enlace de cada producto de una tienda Woocommerce, de forma que si el usuario no esta suscrito, el botón de "Añadir al carrito" pasa a ser "Debes suscribirte" y le envía a la pagina de suscripciones. 
Pero he llegado a un punto muerto y no se por donde avanzar.

Tengo un privilegio "Tienda" que solo se otorga automáticamente a los clientes suscritos. Y es ese privilegio el que uso para comprobar que sean clientes o no.

Ahora no consigo modificar el enlace, o no hay cambios o meto el enlace nuevo a continuación del viejo. Ej:

> midominio.com/?add-to-cart=producto1/midominio.com/suscripciones

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' ); 

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
  if (current_user_can('tienda')) {
         return __( 'Añadir al carrito', 'woocommerce' );
     } elseif (current_user_can('edit_pages')) {
          return __( 'Debes suscribirte', 'woocommerce' );
     }      
}
```

¿Existe algún filtro en la api de Woocommerce para extraer el enlace al carrito de cada producto?

Espero que podáis ayudarme.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4):

Resuelto.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 30, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
  if ( !is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can('tienda') ){
    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){
        $button_text = __( "Debes suscribirte", "woocommerce" );
        $button = '<a class="button" href="https://glancingeye.com/modelado-3d/#suscripcion-modelado">' . $button_text . '</a>';
    }}

    return $button;
}
```